# Date Time conversion error in R - duplicated first time point

Tags: r, datetime, syntax-error

R novice here. 
I have a dataset contain timestamps. 
For example:

```
d <- c("2017-09-17T10:01:23.0000000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0100000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0200000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0300000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0400000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0500000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0600000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0700000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0800000","2017-09-17T10:01:23.0900000")
```

I want to read this into R, so I use `as.POSIXct` as followed:

```
z <- as.POSIXct(d[1:10], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

The result is the following:

```
"2017-09-17 10:01:23.00 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.00 CDT"** "2017-09-17 10:01:23.01 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.02 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.03 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.04 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.05 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.06 CDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.07 CDT" **"2017-09-17 10:01:23.08 CDT"
```

As you can see, the first time point just duplicated after conversion.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all.

Update:
I tried 20 time-points and this happened.

```
t <- c("2017-09-17T11:47:15.5000000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5100000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5200000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5300000",
       "2017-09-17T11:47:15.5400000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5500000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5600000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5700000",
       "2017-09-17T11:47:15.5800000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.5900000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6000000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6100000",
       "2017-09-17T11:47:15.6200000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6300000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6400000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6500000",
       "2017-09-17T11:47:15.6600000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6700000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6800000","2017-09-17T11:47:15.6900000")

z <- as.POSIXct(t[1:20], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

result

```
>"2017-09-17 11:47:15.50 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.50 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.51 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.52 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.53 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.54 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.55 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.56 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.57 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.58 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.59 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.60 CDT" **"2017-09-17 11:47:15.61 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.63 CDT"** "2017-09-17 11:47:15.64 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.65 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.66 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.67 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.68 CDT" "2017-09-17 11:47:15.69 CDT"
```

Comment: Your update has exactly the same issues as your original, (which I explained). Look at `print( as.numeric(z), digits=16)` and `print( as.numeric(z), digits=20)`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the print representation cannot handle the fact that the decimal representation of z[1] is not exact: Look at the difference of the two:

```
> z[1] - z[2]
Time difference of -0.00999999 secs
```

I think that print.POSIXct uses format.POSIXct and it does use the digits.secs option which you can attempt to change. It doesn't really cure the problem on my machine but it's OS specific as far as its effects go.

```
options(digits.secs = 6)
```

One hack that shows that they are not the same is

```
z+0.0001

 [1] "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0000 PDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0100 PDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0200 PDT"
 [4] "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0300 PDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0400 PDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0500 PDT"
 [7] "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0600 PDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0700 PDT" "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0800 PDT"
[10] "2017-09-17 10:01:23.0900 PDT"
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. But d[2] and d[1] do not have a difference. Why would time after conversion lack 0.0001 seconds? 
> difftime(z[2],z[1])
Time difference of 0.00999999 secs
> difftime(d[2],d[1])
Time difference of 0 secs

Comment: I don't understand. `d[1]` and `d[2]` clearly have a difference. With the code `z+0.0001` I added a constant amount to _every_ item in that vector. That's how R works.